# ipython & matplotlib：chart doesn't show in ipython

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

Any help with the issue is appreciated. As the following photo shows, I am trying to get an horizontal bar chart and always get  instead. I don't know what to do with it.

[image]

Comment: If you haven't already, run the `%matplotlib` magic before plotting so that plot windows will pop up. The need for this should go away with matplotlib 2.0.

Comment: It worked!Thanks a lot!! I tried %pylab before and it didn't word. I'm a beginner at this so that I can barely tell the difference. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Reposting as an answer:

If you run the `%matplotlib` magic in IPython before creating plots, the plots will appear automatically, and won't block the prompt.

We're working with matplotlib so that this won't be necessary in matplotlib 2.0.